# Reading car odometer and other car information programmatically

Tags: c#, android, ios, .net, mobile

Are there any standard or standards to connect to any "Smart" cars to read car information such as odometer, speedmeter, GPS information -if exists-? or it is up to the car manufacturer, and are there any APIs for some well-known car manufacturers -such as BMW, FORD, Mercedes-Benz, ...etc-? what is the main communication method? Bluetooth or Wifi?

The platform is not a problem, I need some API for (Android, Windows, iPhone or any other platform).

Comment: Each car type and protocol are up to the car manufacturer. The comm method is most likely Bluetooth as a car as little use for a full network such as WiFi, but I could be wrong. Have you checked the manufacturer's website?

Comment: Thanks @LightStriker I need a common way, to read as many car types as I can, there is no specific car type or manufacturer.

Comment: Bluetooth or Wifi? That's the less common in cars. Especially the Bluetooth Interfaces are most times audio-only. If you want to read more info of your car you Need Access to an cabled Interface, as @mzedeler states below

Comment: The comms method is wired.  Modern cars have a data bus.  There is no bluetooth or WiFi involved (for audio and phone yes, but not for the data).  You would need a can bus interface and plug into the OBD-II port.

Comment: I didn't know cars broadcast this via wireless networks. I may be wrong but as far as I know, this information is only sent via bus systems like CAN, which are not accessible for third party devices such as smartphones. One of the reasons is that the bandwidth is often very carefully calculated. One would not want to have an untested communications partner on the bus. Of course, a dedicated CAN device could broadcast the data in the direction of consumer devices, but if the cellphone integration history is any indicator, this is not going to be standardized soon?

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into the CAN bus protocol. It is becoming the de facto standard for vehicle equipment communication.

Comment: Umm, not quite. It is in fact beginning to _lose_ its dominating role. Also, it's only the current standard for _medium bandwidth data_ communication.

Comment: Well, I like it :) gotto get one of these http://www.superchips.com/Store/iHawk.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid car manufacturers won't give you access over Bluetooth to the inner network the car uses to share information between its components. My guess is, it would be a security hazard for most car manufacturers.

However, if you can modify the car: http://openxcplatform.com/ is an open source and open platform that allows you to connect an Android device to a car, but it does require you to install new hardware on your car and in this case you could add a Bluetooth module.

Yes, the movies where someone take control of a car remotely is pure science-fiction.

Comment: It certainly is not science fiction. Security researchers have managed to take over *all functions of a car except the steering*, which is still mechanical linkage. **All functions**, from changing the radio station to applying the brakes. This is a real problem. Car manufacturers are not taking the security of their embedded systems code *nearly* seriously enough.  http://www.nytimes.com/2011/03/10/business/10hack.html?_r=0  -- note that they managed to do this with both Bluetooth *and by constructing a CD which when played in the car's stereo, took over the car*.

Comment: So, impossible without physical interaction with the inner working of the car?

Comment: They found *eighteen different ways* to take over a car; some of them required physical access, some of them did not. One of the researchers actually wrote a smartphone app that would search a parking lot for a vulnerable car, unlock it and start it remotely. Most of the exploits were straightforward buffer overflows.

Comment: I call bullshit on this. Seriously, if it was that easy, people would do it daily. Hackers and jerks would have the fun of their lives. It wouldn't only be a NYTimes articles, it would be all over the news.

Comment: I assure you, for reals. Security researchers today, car thieves tomorrow. Remember, most car thieves aren't skilled enough to write buffer overrun exploits; that's why they're car thieves and not software engineers. But once organized crime realizes that there's a profit to be made here, it will happen; the app only has to be written once by a bad actor skilled enough to write it. Hopefully the car manufacturers will get their act together before that happens.

Comment: Normally, it goes "hackers first, researchers second". Hackers are very skilled. If they never did it and never released some "hack" online to mess up with people cars, it's possible that it can't be done without physically messing up the car. That NYTimes article is dated back to 2011, you could imagine that hackers would try their hands at that after seeing the news. Most hackers do what they do for the challenge it offers. If they can hack a PS3, I'm pretty sure they would hack the latest BMW if it was that easy.

Comment: So, your argument is "I've never heard of anyone doing this, therefore it's not possible", and my argument is "researchers have done so and reported their findings to the government, therefore it is possible". I like my argument better.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but if you are still looking for an API that allows you to check odometer, location, etc. checkout https://smartcar.com. The Smartcar API allows you to access multiple endpoints across different car brands!

- Odometer        -> https://smartcar.com/product/odometer
- Location        -> https://smartcar.com/product/location
- Lock and unlock -> https://smartcar.com/product/security
- Vin -> https://smartcar.com/product/vin
- General info -> https://smartcar.com/product/vehicle-info